# Regular expression for search terms not preceded or followed by [a-z] and [A-Z]

Tags: mysql, regex

Can someone supply me with a regex to match a search term that is not preceded or followed by `[a-z]` and `[A-Z]`? (Other characters are OK.) I.e., when searching for `key`, I don't want `keyboard` in my search results, but `key.` is okay.

Answer (score 7):

Since you don't specify what regex engine you're using, I'll assume a baseline, in which case "`[^A-Za-z]key[^A-Za-z]`" would be sufficient.

If you also want to catch the string at the start and end of the line, you'll also have to use "`^key[^A-Aa-z]`" and "`[^A-Aa-z]key$`".

Comment: This is the solution that works within a mysql query: WHERE column REGEXP '[^A-Za-z]key[^A-Za-z]' , the word boundary \b does not work in mysql. Thanks!

Comment: Much appreciated - I didn't realize from your question that you were referring to mysql. Now all you need to do is accept the answer :-) .

Comment: One question though. A character is now expected before key. If the value of my column starts with key then the regex does not find it. How can i make it optional?

Comment: According to the MySQL doc Anders linked to, word boundaries are matched with `[[:<:]]` (start of word) and `[[:>:]]` (end of word).

Comment: @Overbeeke: you may need to do WHERE column REGEXP 'regex1' OR column REGEXP 'regex2' OR column REGEXP 'regex3', using the three regexes I gave - the second matches your key at the start, the third matches at the end.

Answer (score 6):

`\bkey\b` should do what you want.

`\b` is a word boundary

Comment: Will this find "_word_" or "word4"?  Are underscores and numbers word boundaries?  +1 or Pax Diablo's answer, which answer the question exactly as asked.

Answer (score 3):

As this question is tagged with [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) I assume you are using MySQL regexps. Then `[[:<:]]key[[:>:]]` is what you want. See the [documentation at dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/regexp.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Perl, what you need is `\b`, aka "word boundary":

```
m/\bkey\b/
```

Comment: I'm gonna use it in a mysql query.

Answer (score 1):

Or the more concise `[^\w]key[^\w]`

Comment: Note that, by requiring a non-word character before and after "key", this will not match "key" at the beginning or end of the line.  (The absence of a character is not a non-word character.)

Answer (score 0):

No need for the `OR`s if you do it like this:

```
(^|[^A-Za-z])key([^A-Za-z]|$)
```